# Howto fix messed-up TOAD configuration - How to open a SQL-Window

Tags: oracle, toad

I am stuck with my daily use of TOAD.

I use Toad in parallel with SQL Developer, because TOAD provides syntax hi-lighted SQL Export und faboulous dependeny tracking with F4. Still most of development of mine is done on SQL developer.

For a few days I struggle with Toad. Sometimes it opens all the editor windows I need on opening, sometime it won't and I can't figure out how to tailor and tame the beast.

I struggle with this situation:

I have connected to target system, but the editor window does not open by itself, neither I can open one manually - see picture.

What is wrong?

How can I tailor toad, to open an SQL editor window, each time a new session is established?

How can I open a SQL-window, eg. how to activate the open editor option in the situation show on the screenshot?

What kind of strange state TOAD is taking in the situation shown?

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot is so small I can't see everything you have going on, but the Editor menu you show contains Editor specific commands that are only enabled when an Editor is opened and active. You don't have one. To open an Editor windows see the Database menu. There's also a toolbar button for it, but it looks as though you only have the Team Coding toolbar active.

Since you are having issues I'd recommend resetting the toolbar layout so that everything is visible again. Right click over Toad's toolbar and choose "Restore defaults."

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually I was constantly trying to open the EDITOR in the EDITOR-Menü. Meanfile I have found the menue path via the DATABASE menü. For my inherited usability genes toad seems to have in different parts a bit a weird menue layout. Anyhow as I like to continue using TOAD I will have to do some extra learning outside inherited routines :-) Thanks again for your helpfull hints.

Comment: Toad's menus could be improved, for sure. In a perfect world the Editor menu would only show when Editor window is active.